# ePay Payment Processor not recognized when adding new payment processor

Tags: wordpress, payment-processor

I've been writing an extension for CiviCRM to add ePay (epay.dk) as a payment processor. I've been following the tutorial at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Example+of+creating+a+payment+processor+extension

My extension is recognized in CiviCRM (running in WordPress) and can be enabled and disabled if I set the extension type to module. If I set it to payment (old style) the extension can't be disabled because it can't find `CRM_Extension_Manager_Payment::CRM_Extension_Manager_Payment::_runPaymentHook` but I have no idea how to fix that.

Anyway, if I want to add a new payment processor under Settings, the drop down menu doesn't show my processor. I've tried to find out how to make it pop up in that menu, but the tutorial doesn't give any clues and Googling has not lead me to an answer either.

Any ideas?